# Invalidating weak hash maps across multiple servers

Tags: scala, caching, playframework, amazon-ec2, redis

We have a Scala Play Framework app running on several EC2 instances that caches a lot of case classes in redis: if the object is in cache then the cached object is returned, else the object is retrieved from the database, put into the cache, and returned.  However, there are a few objects that are frequently referenced (e.g. many objects contain one or more `Location`s, and about 20% of all `Location`s are just the object for the United States as a whole), and so we could reduce memory consumption if we did something like introduce a weak hash map on top of the `Redis` cache.

```
object GetKey {
  def getKey(id: Int, clazz: Class[_]) = clazz.getSimpleName + ":" + id
}

abstract class Record(implicit manifest: Manifest[Record]) {
  val id: Int
  final val key = GetKey.getKey(id, manifest.getClass)
}

object LocalCache {
  private val map = new mutable.WeakHashMap[String, Record]
  def fetch[T](key: String, value: => T) = {
    map.get(key) match {
      case Some(t) => t.asInstanceOf[T]
      case _ => {
        val temp = value
        if(temp.key != key) throw new IllegalArgumentException("key mismatch")
        map.put(temp.key, temp)
        temp
}}}}

object Redis {
  def fetch[T](key: String, value: => T) = {
    this.get(key) match {
      case Some(t) => t.asInstanceOf[T]
      case _ => {
        val temp = value
        this.put(key, value)
        temp
}}}}

object RecordDAO {
  val recordClass: Class[_] // same as Record's manifest.getClass
  def getById(id: Int): Record = {
    def getFromDb(id): Record = { ... }
    def getFromRedis(key: String): Record = Redis.fetch(key, getFromDb(id))
    def getFromLocalCache(key: String): Record = LocalCache.fetch(key, getFromRedis(key))
    getFromLocalCache(GetKey.getKey(id, recordClass))  
  }
}
```

The `Redis` code is already in place, the `LocalCache` code is what we'd like to add to it.  All record types inherit from `Record`, so `Redis` and `LocalCache` retrieve Records and then cast them to the appropriate type.  The application first looks for an object in `LocalCache`; if it's present the object is returned, else the application looks for the object in `Redis`; if it's present the object is returned, else the application retrieves the object from the database.  If the object is missing from `Redis` and or `LocalCache` then it's added; `LocalCache` uses `temp.key` to add the object to the weak hash map so that it will hold a string reference to the hash key (however if the object accidentally gets GC'd early then this is sub-optimal but won't break anything).

The problem is that we don't have a good way to invalidate `LocalCache` - at present if for example the name of the United States changes then we clear the `Location` from `Redis` (we don't worry about the `Location` objects that are already in memory, for example if a `User`'s `Location` is the United States, and we change the `Location` name to USA, then the `User` will still see that they're in the United States until they get a new browser session), but we need a way to communicate the cache invalidation to all of the EC2 instances so that they can remove the `Location` from their `LocalCache`s.  We could do something like add a version number or a timestamp to the objects in `Redis` and have `LocalCache` invalidate an object if the object's version number / timestamp doesn't match the one in Redis, but this means we'll be doing two `Redis` get calls instead of one.

Ideally we'd like to set up a mailbox on each EC2 instance to which we can pass cache invalidation messages.  We already have a RabbitMQ instance for sending messages to an ElasticSearch instance, but I wasn't sure if there was already a utility for this sort of thing in EC2 - I'm a complete novice at EC2.

What would be the best way for me to invalidate keys in weak hash maps spread across multiple EC2 instances?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using RabbitMQ I would recommend using that to minimize the number of technologies in your stack.

Amazon does have a messaging service, Simple Queue Service (SQS) but you would also need to use another Amazon service, Simple Notification Service (SNS), to get publish/subscribe functionality.  See the FAQ "Q: How can I fanout identical messages to multiple SQS queues?" at http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/.